# jQuery change value of html input onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attr

I need to change the value of the url of the onclick portion of my input tags

```
<input type="image" onclick="return launchEditor('image1', 'http://images.aviary.com/imagesv5/feather_default.jpg');" />
```

I have the needed url being dynamically stored in a variable on hover function.

```
$('ul.photos img').hover(function(){
var imgSrc = $(this).attr("src");
```

How can I take this variable and plug it into the needed area?
Thanks for any help

Comment: I suggest replacing the onclick attribute with a jQuery event handler.

Comment: @Tuan why? Event handlers are harder to debug, and usually require a fallback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
<input type="image" onclick="return launchEditor('image1', window.foo);" />
```

And the hover callback:

```
$('ul.photos img').hover(function(){
    window.foo = $(this).attr("src");
});
```

Replace `foo` by anything you want.

But some more details on what it should do would let us help you better. Even though this should work, it's probably not the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you have that local variable in your hover handler, you either will have to make it globally available and use it in the onclick function, or you will have to change the onclick function (here: attribute) in the hover handler.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to add:

```
<input onmouseover="this.onclick=function(){ [javascript] }"/>
```

with `[javascript]` being the code you want executed on click.